# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'u' occurs when plotting from a specific file

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My code to plot the graph from 2 xlsx files, is given below.

The two files from which I import data to plot the graph are similar (except values). Still I am getting this error on one file.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.image as image
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from tkinter import filedialog
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', True)
files1 = filedialog.askopenfilename(multiple=True) 
files = root.tk.splitlist(files1)
List = list(files) 

%gui tk
Str=''.join(List)
fname = Str.split('.')[0]

#plotting
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30, 20))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax1 =ax.twinx()
ax.grid(True,axis='both')
#ax.set(xlabel="Voltage", ylabel="Current", title="IV Curve") 
ax.set_xlabel("Module Voltage [V]",fontsize = 20)
ax1.set_xlabel("Module Voltage [V]",fontsize = 20)
ax.set_ylabel("Module Current [I]",fontsize = 20)
ax1.set_ylabel("Module Power [W]",fontsize = 20)
ax1.spines['right'].set_color('red')
ax.spines['left'].set_color('red')
ax.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax, ax1)
#ax.set_title("IV/PV Curve Plot",fontweight ='bold', fontsize = 30, color='blue')
ax1.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', labelsize=20)
ax.set_ylim (0,10) #adjust the current limits
ax.set_xlim (0,70) #adjust the voltage limits
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', labelsize=20)
ax1.set_ylim  (0,500) #adjust the power limits
ax1.set_xlim (0,70) #adjust the voltage limits

for i,file in enumerate(List):
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    ax.plot('Voltage', 'Current', data=df, linewidth=2)
    ax1.plot('Voltage', 'Power', data=df, linewidth=2)
    ax.legend( loc='upper right',fontsize=20)
    ax1.legend(loc='lower right',fontsize=20)
    #pmax and Vmax
    Pmax = df["Power"].max()
    maxrow = df[df['Power']==Pmax]
    Voltage = maxrow['Voltage'].iloc[0]
    Current = maxrow['Current'].iloc[0]
    xmax1 =(Voltage/70)
    xmax2 =(Current/10)
    ax.axhline(y=Current, xmin=0, xmax =xmax1,linewidth=2, color ='g',linestyle='--',)
    ax.axvline(x=Voltage, ymin=0, ymax =xmax2, linewidth=2, color='g', linestyle='--')


img = image.imread("/home/hebin/Desktop/PV/Mitsui/Flasher/logo.png")
plt.figimage(img, 1380, 1120, alpha=1)
plt.tight_layout()
#plt.savefig(fname + "IV_comaprison_M19.png")

print(f'IV: {file}')
```

test files : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sL2-CwCGeGm0-fvcpzMVzgFnYzN3wzVb?usp=sharing

I checked both the files, but one files shows the above error while plotting.

### Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-64f3b146189f> in <module>
     28 #     df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
     29 
---> 30     ax.plot('Voltage', 'Current', data=df, linewidth=2)
     31     ax1.plot('Voltage', 'Power', data=df, linewidth=2)
     32     ax.legend( loc='upper right',fontsize=20)

e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1741         """
   1742         kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D)
-> 1743         lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1744         for line in lines:
   1745             self.add_line(line)

e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in __call__(self, data, *args, **kwargs)
    271                 this += args[0],
    272                 args = args[1:]
--> 273             yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
    274 
    275     def get_next_color(self):

e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    367     def _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs):
    368         if len(tup) > 1 and isinstance(tup[-1], str):
--> 369             linestyle, marker, color = _process_plot_format(tup[-1])
    370             tup = tup[:-1]
    371         elif len(tup) == 3:

e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _process_plot_format(fmt)
    155             i += 1
    156         elif c == 'C' and i < len(fmt) - 1:
--> 157             color_cycle_number = int(fmt[i + 1])
    158             color = mcolors.to_rgba("C{}".format(color_cycle_number))
    159             i += 2

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'u'
```

### Sample Data

- `'IV_MCIND_17_after.xlsx'`

```py
 Voltage, Current,Power
-1.31162533333333,9.250545,-12.13324916914
-1.31057466666667,9.25027833333333,-12.1231804432822
-1.30847366666667,9.249613,-12.1028750373577
-1.309522,9.24855,-12.1111796931
-1.309521,9.24815166666667,-12.110648818685
-1.31057066666667,9.24788733333333,-12.1200098677049
-1.30952,9.24748733333333,-12.1097696127467
-1.31161966666667,9.24708966666667,-12.1286646662301
-1.310569,9.24708966666667,-12.1189490573537
-1.309519,9.24668966666667,-12.1087158056037
-1.307418,9.24615766666667,-12.088592964238
-1.307417,9.24575933333333,-12.0880629303087
-1.30636566666667,9.24535966666667,-12.0778204445181
-1.305315,9.244828,-12.06741266082
-1.30846533333333,9.24469666666667,-12.0963651055156
```

- `'IV_MCIND_17_before.xlsx'`

```py
Voltage,Current,Power
-1.2434153333333333,9.252745333333333,-11.505005422895112
-1.2402546666666667,9.252215,-11.475102830753334
-1.2402543333333333,9.251950666666668,-11.474771906119557
-1.2392006666666668,9.251818,-11.464859033478668
-1.2381469999999999,9.251552666666667,-11.454782179575332
-1.237094,9.251552333333333,-11.445039882252665
-1.2370933333333332,9.251155,-11.444542176133332
-1.2391986666666668,9.250625333333334,-11.463362578899558
-1.2391976666666666,9.249963333333334,-11.462532979418889
-1.2391966666666667,9.249434,-11.461867781353336
-1.2391953333333332,9.248772,-11.461035101463999
-1.2391953333333332,9.248507666666667,-11.460707540830889
-1.237088,9.248109333333334,-11.440725078954667
-1.232875,9.247844,-11.4014356715
-1.2318209999999998,9.247313,-11.391034346972999
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Both files were loaded into separate dataframes, and plotted without issue, which provided validation for the numeric column values.
- `df.info()` showed an issue with the column names.
- The issue is that `'IV_MCIND_17_after.xlsx'` has whitespace in the column names.

  - `Index([' Voltage', ' Current', 'Power'], dtype='object')`
  - Removing the whitespace in the column names, resolves the issue.

    - `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()`
- The code unnecessary for reproducing the error has been removed.

  - Comment out the line that fixes the column names, and the error will occur.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# files
l1 = ['IV_MCIND_17_before.xlsx', 'IV_MCIND_17_after.xlsx']

#plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
ax1 =ax.twinx()
ax.grid(True,axis='both')

for i, file in enumerate(l1):
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    
    # clean column names
    df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
    
    ax.plot('Voltage', 'Current', data=df, linewidth=2)
    ax1.plot('Voltage', 'Power', data=df, linewidth=2)
```

[image]